# Expected value of uniform distribution

Tags: probability

Given that *r.v* will be from $2$ to $10$, each having $\frac18$ probability.
$$E(X)=\frac18(2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10)$$

Am I wrong? Because the answer given was $6$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $9$ numbers from $2$ to $10$. The probability of each number should be $\frac19$.

Comment: I guess you are right, didn't notice the mistake from the question